# Security implication of allowing attributes while sanitising HTML using DOMPurify

Tags: javascript, xss, dompurify

I am using [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) to sanitize HTML to prevent XSS.

`const sanitizedHtml = DOMPurify.sanitize(htmlString);`

The the problem is by default DOMPurify doesn't honor attributes of HTML tags. In my case, I have an anchor element with `target` attribute and that sanitized HTML removes the `target` attribute.

From the documentation I found that the following code fix this issue:

`const sanitizedHtml = DOMPurify.sanitize(htmlString, { ADD_ATTR: ['target'] });`

However, my question is that if DOMPurify is removing all the attributes then there has to be some reason behind that. So if I allow some specific attribute as mentioned above, am I opening up any security risk (of XSS attack)?

Answer (score 2):

While this might be a bit late, I'm currently doing some research on the topic myself. Maybe it will help someone in the future.

Simply allowing the attribute `target` can open you up to security issues as stated [here](https://web.dev/external-anchors-use-rel-noopener/).

An issue for allowing `target=_blank` does exist, but it was closed, as the author did not see it as a feature they would like to implement.

It seems like it is recommended to use hooks (samples can be found in the link) to achieve this functionality.